# WinRT Bindable Highlight TextBlock control

Tags: xaml, binding, windows-runtime, highlight, textblock

I'm developing WinRT / windows store app.

Is there any way how i could highlight certain text in TextBlock?
something like that:

```
<controls:TextBlockHighlight Text="{Binding Text}" HighlightText="{Binding HighlightText}" />
```

I managed to get required output with

```
<TextBlock>
  <TextBlock.Text>
    <Run>......</Run>
  </TextBlock.Text>
</Textblock>
```

But i need that control to be bindable, and i don't how to make it like that..

Comment: Let me try to add that to the toolkit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Filip,

Many thanks for addition in framework.

Highlight textblock behavior is now available in http://winrtxamltoolkit.codeplex.com/

Regards